# calculate mean for subgroups

Tags: r, plyr

I want to calculate the month value by calculating the mean of the weeksums per month.

e.g. for June (06) and distance 10 I have the weeksums 1(2017_28), 6(2017_29) and 1 (2017_31), I want to summarise these weeks to get the total monthsum 8 and the mean value 2.6667 (8:3).

I got the monthsum but I don't know how to calculate the mean

```r
df %>% 
  group_by(year_month, distance) %>%
  mutate(monthsum = sum(weeksum))
```

```
   year year_month month year_week distance weeksum
1   2017    2017_05    05   2017_21       15       4
2   2017    2017_05    05   2017_21       10       1
3   2017    2017_05    05   2017_22        5       5
4   2017    2017_05    05   2017_22        0       1
5   2017    2017_06    06   2017_22        0      11
6   2017    2017_06    06   2017_23       20       7
7   2017    2017_06    06   2017_23        0       6
8   2017    2017_07    07   2017_28       10       1
9   2017    2017_07    07   2017_28        0       1
10  2017    2017_07    07   2017_29       10       6
11  2017    2017_07    07   2017_29        5       3
12  2017    2017_07    07   2017_30        0      12
13  2017    2017_07    07   2017_31       10       1
14  2017    2017_07    07   2017_31        0       7
```

This is what I want:

```
   year year_month month year_week distance monthsum    mean
1   2017    2017_05    05   2017_21       15       4      4
2   2017    2017_05    05   2017_21       10       1      1
3   2017    2017_05    05   2017_22        5       5      5
4   2017    2017_05    05   2017_22        0       1      1
5   2017    2017_06    06   2017_22        0      17    8.5
6   2017    2017_06    06   2017_23       20       7      7
7   2017    2017_07    07   2017_28       10       8 2.6667
8   2017    2017_07    07   2017_28        0      20 6.6667
9  2017    2017_07    07   2017_29        5       3      3
```

Comment: Isn't adding `monthmean = mean(weeksum))` to your `mutate` statement give what you want ? `df %>% group_by(year_month, distance) %>% mutate(monthsum = sum(weeksum), 
                                                 monthmean = mean(weeksum))`

Answer (score 0):

First of, I hope you use `dplyr`and not `plyr` to be up to date.

Also simply extend your statement with a `mean()` function like this:

```
df %>% 
   group_by(year_month, distance) %>% 
   mutate(monthsum = sum(weeksum), monthmean = mean(weeksum))
```

Also in your case use `summarize`instead of `mutate` to get a better view:

```
df %>% 
   group_by(year_month, distance) %>% 
   summarize(monthsum = sum(weeksum), monthmean = mean(weeksum))
```